# jQuery Mobile + jQuery UI google maps + Fusion Markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery-mobile, geolocation, google-fusion-tables

this has been baking my noodle for months, I'll be honest, I am a designer not a programmer so this type of scripting is a bit harder than the average jquery/javascript that I'm used too.

I can't find any basic documentation on how to implement it, apart from this but it's not massively intuitive - **http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html**

I've tried making a JSfiddle, but I can't even get it to work **(now working thanks to Tsar)**

I've built a jQuery mobile app and I'm desperate to get the geo-location functionality working with fusion table markers (from my fusion table) and to be allowed to click on the fusion table markers to reveal a info window. This info window will be constructed in fusion tables.

I need the geo-location to center the map on the devices current location - if the geo-location is not available or denied by device user, then the map needs to be centered on these co-ordinates 52.450939, -1.721002.

What would be the next level is to have the the jQuery mobile UI pop-up window but this is not critical, just the standard bubble on the map is fine.

A updated JSFiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/twGHC/30/

My fusion table number is: **1260763**

Default location is: (only if Geo location is not available) **52.450939, -1.721002**

Zoom level: **13**

Any advice would be awesome, please feel free to JSfiddle it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working solution, which detects user's location, drops a marker on it and plots the map with your Fusion Markers. As per [Google Maps v3 API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html):

```
$(function() {
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(52.450939, -1.721002);

  getCurrentPosition = function(callback) {
    // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(pos) {
          position = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
            callback(position);
          }, callback(position));         
    } // Try Google Gears Geolocation
    else if (google.gears) {
      var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
      geo.getCurrentPosition(
        function(pos) {
          position = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.latitude,pos.longitude);
          callback(position);
        }, callback(position));          
    } // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    else {
      // Drop the user off in Coventry =)
      callback(position);
    }
  };
     // call the above function
  getCurrentPosition(InitMap);
});

function InitMap(pos) {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: pos,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos, 
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    map: map, 
    title: "You are here, mate!"
  });   

var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'Geocodable address',
    from: '1260763'
    },
  });

  layer.setMap(map);
};
```

When user denies tracking of his location, exception is caught in `getCurrentPosition`, however, 2nd optional parameter in this function is an exception handler, so what I did is simply passed in `callback(position)` so that default location sets on the map. If you don't want to do it, move out the map initializer code from `InitMap` into separate function and call it instead, when exceptions are caught, to display a blank map.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/twGHC/36/

P.S. In case your next question is "how to add a balloon pop-up on marker click", [here's what you need to do](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows).

Comment: Thanks for getting the JSfiddle example to work - I had this working in my mobile app - but its just the complicated issue of now trying to get GEO location functionality built in.

Comment: you haven't mentioned exactly what you want to do with the "geo-location". Do you want to get user's location and centre the map on it?

Comment: Sorry I must of missed that - will update.

Yes Geo location to find your current location on the map and center it like you said. But if geo location is denied or not available, then it jumps to those coordinates.

Comment: Hi Tsar - thanks so much for this - you seem to understand this so much better than I can, you have answered everything I've asked. I've had a look at the documentation and I cant figure out where I need to put the code to 'add a marker' on the current position - could you help me add this in your source above? Do you have a donation button or paypal account I can buy you a few beers. 

I have noticed on iphone if you press 'Don't allow' on the Geo Location, the map does not actually appear on those co-ordinates, just a grey background appears. Not a problem if you can't fix this. Many Thanks!

Comment: hi,there's no need to pay me,this site is free to use and i'm taking as well as giving on it. just one thing: you need to stop asking additional questions and instead, upvote & accept the answer and then start a new question. the more you ask here, the more your question becomes tailored to yourself, hence it may not be of help to anyone else. Questions have to be more "generic" here.

Comment: Hi, yeah quite new to this - will do, thanks for the heads up! Josh

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with jquery-ui-map:
http://jsfiddle.net/rweCf/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/rweCf/1/embedded/result/

If you just want to change within a certain radius of the client position this is how you would do it
http://jsfiddle.net/Ywknf/1/ (client location is the initial point so everyone can see the results)

Here is the code if the url isnt working or the trunk code changed

```
$(function() {

  $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': '52.450939, -1.721002', 'zoom': 10, 'disableDefaultUI': true, 'mapTypeId': 'terrain'}).bind('init', function(event, map) { 
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(results, status) {
            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                var position = new google.maps.LatLng(results.coords.latitude, results.coords.longitude);
                var marker = $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'markers > client' );
                if ( !marker ) {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'id': 'client', 'position': position, 'bounds': true });
                } else {
                    marker.setPosition(position);
                    map.panTo(position);
                }
            } else if ( status === 'NOT_SUPPORTED' ) {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'id': 'client', 'position': $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map').getCenter(), 'bounds': true });
            }
        });
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('loadFusion', { 'query': { 'select': 'Geocodable address', 'from': 1260763 } } );
    });  

});
```